# How to get the command line arguments running java in IntelliJ IDEA 14.1

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I have a java project and I can run it by `Editing Configurations` in IntelliJ IDEA by specifying the `Program Arguments`.

However, I am wondering how to get the overall command line arguments when IntelliJ runs this program since this program is configured through gradle and
the classpath is complicated and I do not know how to get this classpath. In eclipse, I know, that by using the debugger I can get this whole command line arguments.

I want the command line arguments since I want to run the same program with different input files so that I hope to have a loop of the file names to be combined with other command line arguments together. I did not want to provide each input file manually by specifying the ``program arguments" myself and run the program each time with a new input file manually.

If there is a way to complete this by writing a java program, I also welcome the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you hit the `Run`/`Debug` buttons, you will see a small "view" window named (also) `Run`; and right away you can get the command with the `classpath` declaration(s).

[image]